# what is the pros and cons of using out parameter

Tags: c#, .net

Anyone can point out the pros and cons of the out parameter. When it is preferred to use out parameter rather than just to return a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) methods on the built in types like int.  The return value is a bool to indicate success while the value is returned via an out parameter.  This construct makes it useful to call this method in a looping construct where another return type would/might make it a bit more complicated.

On further reflection one con could be a tendency to just keep adding out parameters to a method instead of properly encapsulating the logic.

Comment: want to know why the boolean return is good in the loop? Can you give example?

Comment: @user496949 - with the TryParse methods, you can handle a failure to parse fairly simply by looking at the return of the method.   That saves you from trying to either handle the parsing exception or looking for something that indicates the resultant value is somehow invalid.   Consider a boolean as probably the simplest example.   Aside from an exception, how would one know that a resultant value was "invalid"?    With tryParse, the method itself indicates success, and the resultant value was either correctly parsed to a new value or remains as it was before the method was called.

Comment: I think you hit on the major drawback. From what I can tell, every out param. requires maintenance of another variable by the object invoking the method.   It's not a "big deal" to delcare a couple of extra variables along the way, but it does have a big protential to become unneccessarily cumbersome, when, the method can just as easily (and probably more properly) encapsulate all of that information into its returned value.

Comment: I've always thought of out parameters as a bit of a minor code smell, since they tend to suggest that you have a method that does more than one thing which likely should be factored out into separate methods.  While trying to create some coding guidelines for junior developers at work, I did some research and decided that I could *not* say to *never* use out parameters, since sometimes they are a useful and necessary construct, such as cases when refactoring into multiple methods would result in additional round trips to the database.

Answer (score 7):

Out parameters effectively allow you to return multiple values from a method, and this is generally preferable to returning an arbitrary struct or tuple which contains multiple values.

One might argue that it's easier to overlook the possible side effects of a function which uses an out parameter, as it departs from the traditional 'multiple parameters, one return value' model. But I honestly think that the out keyword coupled with a method post-condition makes the programmer's intention quite clear.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with the notion that it is generally preferable to have "out" values instead of return objects, but maybe it's because I'm not quite interpretting arbitrary as you intended.  To me, a collection of return values (proprties w/in a single return object), generally provides more flexibility than a list of variables that have to be declared and maintained, but I would agree that there's good cases for both situations.  They seem to make perfect sense in TryParse type methods, where, I agree, a "special" structure of <var type> + bool (success?) seems overkill.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can't return multiple variables, so you might do the job by using the out parameter, if you don't want to go through a class (return a class with those multiple variables).